# Pass Firebase Props onclick to methods in Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuefire

I would like to pass my `props.items` to the methods to change/delete the value of it afterwards in Firebase. I'm doing this by `@click`, but Vue won't allow `props.item.id` in the method declaration. What am I missing?

```html
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="products"
      :sort-by="['description']"
      :search="search"
      :items-per-page="15"
      class="elevation-1">
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props" >

    <td><v-chip small>{{props.item.id}}</v-chip></td>
    <td>{{props.item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{props.item.description}}</td>
    <td>{{props.item.price}}</td>
    <td>{{props.item.ingredients}}</td>
    <td>
      <v-chip small>{{props.item.type}}</v-chip>
    </td>
    <td><v-btn  @click="onDelete(props.item.id)" class="material-icons medium">delete</v-btn></td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

And the script excerpt:

```js
export default {
    methods: {
       onDelete(props.item.id) {
         // ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `onDelete(props.item.id) {}` is not a valid method declaration, as the parameter name cannot be `props.item.id`.

Comment: I think your already pass as `props.item.id` in onclick , so the parameter on your `onDelete` will be `id` only :>

Answer (score 0):

The method declaration for `onDelete` is invalid because the argument identifier cannot be `props.item.id` (i.e., the dots are not allowed for the name). The valid characters for an [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) are Unicode letters, `$`, `_`, or digits (0-9).

Given the purpose of the argument, I'd rename it to `itemId`:

```js
methods: {
  onDelete(itemId) {
    // ...
  }
}
```